# UILabel always unwrapping as nil when trying to change text value

Tags: swift, uilabel, null

I have a tableview with a list of sports and I want to open up the corresponding team page for each cell. In my team page I have a label which is suppose to change text depending on which cell you press from the list of sports. I passed the string from a segue correctly and my print lines show that the string is correct. However when I try to set the text of my label, there is an "unexpectedly found nil" error. My label is connected in IB correctly and is instantiated. It seems so simple but has been bugging me forever.

Here is my sport list controller segue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showTeamPage"{
        let teamViewController: TeamPage = segue.destinationViewController as! TeamPage
        teamViewController.teamSport = sport
    }


    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
```

And here is the TeamPage() code:

```
   import UIKit
   import Social
   import CloudKit

   class TeamPage: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UIAlertViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var sportTitle: UILabel!

var teamSport: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.sportTitle = UILabel()

    println(teamSport)

    self.sportTitle.text = teamSport

    println(sportTitle.text)

}
```

I'm going insane...

Comment: Are you setting `teamSport` to something other than `nil` before assigning the `text` of `sportTitle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the compiler is confused because you're re-initializing the label. My guess is that when you made the call `self.sportTitle = UILabel()`, ARC kicks in to kill off the sportTitle UILabel! that you've made via a storyboard connection. And then, for some reason, `self.sportTitle.text = teamSport` tries to set the text of nil (since it's been destroyed due to your previous step).

To solve this, delete `self.sportTitle = UILabel()`. You don't need that.

Comment: That was it! But what doesn't make sense to me is that I didn't have that line there before and it didn't work then. I added it because I thought for some reason maybe the label wasn't being instantiated. I must have solved some other issue in the process but made another by adding that line. Thanks thought!